# what is logh and logs in objective-c?

Tags: objective-c, xcode

[image: logh and logs in xcode]

I tried typing the same code, but i am getting a warning: *Implicit declaration of function 'logh' is invalid in C99.* 
Do I need to install something, does someone has experience with this? Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Where do you got this from? It's not a Objective-C method, it must be a C or C++ method, accepting an `NSString *` (and logh also accepts a block).
I believe it's not a method in CoreFoundation or Foundation.framework, since Foundation.framework is ObjC and CoreFoundation prefixed everything with `CF`

Comment: i was watching this tutorials: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0TKhHyIHTJA&feature=player_detailpage&list=PL2bpbV1ZZWXebKpNU4Ru9Y_Azfm3RbYo6#t=358

Comment: It must be some method which he has written himself, looks like it's not part of any Apple framework.

Comment: Or some _clever_ macro. This doesn't come with Objective-C/C or any known framework. Rewind to 00:04 and there's _Working Files for this movie can be found in the Working Files Folder_. You need this folder. Where you get it? Ask author of this video.

Comment: @robertvojta preprocessor macros are blue in Xcodes default color scheme. It's a function according to the color scheme.

Comment: well, that makes sense but this tutorial is for beginners, and it is confusing. But I'll ask!

Comment: @Leandros if it is default color scheme. You never know what users did to it ;-)

Comment: If you copy stuff from the internet, it's your job to make it work. You copied something that isn't complete. Tough.

Comment: it is copied from tutorial, and if i knew what it is, i wouldn't ask here!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's from Strings-prefix.pch in Supporting Files group:

```
 //
// Prefix header for all source files of the 'String' target in the 'String' project
//

#ifdef __OBJC__
    #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

typedef void(^LogBlock)(void);

static void logh(NSString *header, LogBlock logBlock) { 
    printf("== %s ==\n", [header cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);
    logBlock();
    printf("\n");
}

static void logs(NSString *str) {
    printf("> '%s'\n", [str cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);
}

#endif
```

I found this course at [Udemy.](https://www.udemy.com/the-art-of-real-ios-programming/) It's outdated, but very useful for me to step into iOS apps development, Objective-C particularly.